# Nhibernation InMemory Database Setup error

Tags: .net, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Im having an issue with setting up a SQLite inMemory database, i have installed sqlite from here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

I recieve this Nhibernate exception

> SQL logic error or missing database, unknown database core

when trying to run a unit test, the exception is raised at the BuildSchema method

Here is my Factory code

```
Imports NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl

Namespace SessionManager
    Public Class Factory
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

    Private Shared _configuration As NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration
    Private Shared _sessionFactory As NHibernate.ISessionFactory

    Public Shared Function OpenTestSession() As NHibernate.ISession
        If SessionFactory Is Nothing Then
            SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory()
            Dim sx = SessionFactory.OpenSession()
            'BuildSchema2(sx)
            Return sx
        End If
    End Function

    Private Shared Function CreateSessionFactory() As NHibernate.ISessionFactory
        Return FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure().Database(GetInMemoryDataBaseConfiguration()).Mappings(Sub(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of ModelEntity)()).ExposeConfiguration(Sub(Cfg) BuildSchema3(Cfg)).BuildSessionFactory()
    End Function

    Private Shared Function CreateSessionFactory2() As NHibernate.ISessionFactory
        Return FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure().Database(GetInMemoryDataBaseConfiguration()).Mappings(Sub(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of ModelEntity)()).ExposeConfiguration(Function(Cfg) InlineAssignHelper(_configuration, Cfg)).BuildSessionFactory()
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub BuildSchema(config As NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration)
        Dim se = New SchemaExport(config)
        se.Create(False, True)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub BuildSchema2(sx As NHibernate.ISession)
        Dim se = New SchemaExport(_configuration)
        se.Execute(True, True, False, sx.Connection, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub BuildSchema3(config As NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration)
        Dim se = New SchemaExport(config)
        se.Create(True, True)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetInMemoryDataBaseConfiguration() As FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.SQLiteConfiguration
        Return FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory()
    End Function

    Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(target As T, value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function

End Class
```

> End Namespace

If anybody known of a solution or point me towards a solution, i will gift points :)

**EDIT**

SQLite appears to have issues with our SQL Server schemas, when i map a table without a Schema it works.... Any ideas of how to get the mapping to ignore the schema from the table mapping :).

Further to this i have found linked questions to this...
[Fluent NHibernate - Remove Schema from Mappings for Testing With SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822909/fluent-nhibernate-remove-schema-from-mappings-for-testing-with-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be on the right track - though I don't think you'll be able to get it to ignore the schema in the mapping, short of implementing your own dialect or something like that.  Instead, since you're using Fluent NHibernate to generate your mappings, ask it to generate mappings without the schemas.  Your ClassMaps, AutoMappingOverrides, and Conventions are all just code, after all.  One way to do this would be like so:

Create a place to store the setting that can be changed at runtime:

```
public static class MappingOptions
{
    public static readonly ThreadLocal<bool> ForSQLite = new ThreadLocal<bool>();
}
```

Set it before asking FluentNHibernate to generate the mappings, and then check it where needed:

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        if (!MappingOptions.ForSQLite.Value)
            Schema("core");
        Table("Employee");
        // ... other stuff ...
    }
}
```